# avoid spaces when concatenating variables in bash under macos

Tags: bash, macos

I am having a strange issue with `bash` under macos. When I concatenate two variables, it adds an extra space between them which I cannot get rid of.

```
~/testdrive/dir1 $ curd=$(pwd)
~/testdrive/dir1 $ echo $curd
/xx/xx/testdrive/dir1
~/testdrive/dir1 $ fcount=$(ls -l | wc -l)
~/testdrive/dir1 $ echo $fcount
5          # notice no space in front of the 5 
~/testdrive/dir1 $ echo $curd$fcount
/xx/xx/testdrive/dir1 5 # space between directory name and 5
```

I am using GNU bash, Version 5.0.16(1)-release (x86_64-apple-darwin19.3.0). I tried newd="$curd$fcount" and newd=${curd}${fcount} with the same result. In some directories it adds 5 or more spaces between the variables.

However,

```
~/testdrive/dir1 $ var1=abc
~/testdrive/dir1 $ var2=def
~/testdrive/dir1 $ echo $var1$var2
abcdef   # expected behavior
```

Then, again,

```
~/testdrive/dir1 $ echo $var1$fcount
abc 5  # space between
```

I've seen many tips how to remove whitespace from strings, however I do not understand why it is there in the first place. I am assuming it has to do with `fcount=$(ls -l | wc -l)` but how?  Any ideas?

Comment: Try `echo "$fcount"` and check for spaces again...

Comment: Try telling `bash` that `fcount` is an integer, with `declare -i fcount`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bash variables are untyped. Try this:

```
fcount=$(ls | wc -l)

echo $fcount          # check it
469                   # it looks ok, but...

echo "$fcount"        # ... when quoted properly
     469              # it has leading spaces! UGH!
```

Try again, but this time tell `bash` it's an integer:

```
declare -i fcount     # Tell bash it's an integer
fcount=$(ls | wc -l)  # set it
echo "$fcount"        # check value with correct quoting
469                   # and it's correct
```

---

Or, if you don't like that method, you can tell `bash` to replace all spaces with nothing/emptiness.

```
string="   abc  |"

echo "$string"           # display string as is
   abc  |

echo "${string// /}"     # delete all spaces in string
abc|
```

Comment: Humm, I cannot replicate your `echo $fcount` versus `echo "$fcount"` difference on any version of `bash` on Linux distributions.

Comment: Declaring it an integer works, thank you! still wondering, why, though :)

Comment: Why? Because `bash` thinks it's a string with spaces at the front.

Comment: I have added another method if declaring it as an integer isn't intuitive to you.

Comment: I do like declaring it as an integer, it works for me and I already updated my script, so big thank you! I am also getting that bash considers the output of "wc -l" as a string. Just not getting why it would think that six spaces belong in front of it unlike it does with the other string in curd=$(pwd)...

Comment: That's easy :-) Run `ls -l | wc -l` in your Terminal and you will see that `wc` makes those spaces.

Comment: I'm guessing your next question will be *"Why does `wc` do that?"* That's also easy :-) If you run `ls -l | wc` you will see it counts lines, words and characters, but separates the 3 numbers with whitespace.

Answer (score 0):

It works for me :

```
 $ name='john'
 $ age='5'
 $ echo "${name}${age}"
john5
```

I am using :

```
GNU bash, version 3.2.57(1)-release (x86_64-apple-darwin18)
Copyright (C) 2007 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
```

Please try to replicate this in your version. Otherwise this might work too :

```
$ newvalue=$( printf "%s%s\n" $name $age )
$ echo "$newvalue" 
john5
```

Comment: The issue is that there **are** spaces at the start of OP's `$fcount` He just can't see them because he didn't double quote.

Comment: Ok, I do see spaces when I double quote:

`
⌘  ~ $ var1="test"
⌘  ~ $ var2="$(ls -l | wc -l)"
⌘  ~ $ echo $var2
26
⌘  ~ $ echo $var1$var2
test 26
⌘  ~ $ echo "$var1""$var2"
test      26
⌘  ~ $ echo "$var1$var2"
test      26
`

Six of them if I double quote, 1 space if I don't. As a side note: this only seems to happen if I create a variable which holds the output of 'wc -l', not in any other case. Seems weird to me :)